# What is the equivalent of the collection.getIndexes() shell command in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I can't seem to find a getIndexes() command implemented as part of pymongo's Collection object - is that intentional? is it implemented somewhere else in the class hierarchy?

if it isn't, what's the pymongo canonical way for getting the same effect?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What you might be looking for is [`index_information()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.index_information) at the Collection level. From the docs:

> Get information on this collection’s indexes.
>
> Returns a dictionary where the keys are index names (as returned by create_index()) and the values are dictionaries containing information about each index.

```
>>> db.test.index_information()
{u'_id_': {u'key': [(u'_id', 1)]},
u'x_1': {u'unique': True, u'key': [(u'x', 1)]}}
```